# NSPersistentCloudKitContainer “Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception.” Error

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

When I use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to sync data, I receive error `Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception.`:

```
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _requestAbortedNotInitialized:](1826): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x282f3c180> - Never successfully initialized and cannot execute request '<NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest: 0x2815d8180> B7974D4D-C5DA-413E-AE3B-072C88D38D47' due to error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134421 "Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception., NSUnderlyingException=*** NSAllocateMemoryPages(103626821) failed}
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _finishedRequest:withResult:](2713): Finished request: <NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest: 0x2815d8180> B7974D4D-C5DA-413E-AE3B-072C88D38D47 with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x281b51060> success: 0 madeChanges: 0 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134406 "Request 'B7974D4D-C5DA-413E-AE3B-072C88D38D47' was aborted because the mirroring delegate never successfully initialized due to error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134421 "Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception., NSUnderlyingException=*** NSAllocateMemoryPages(103626821) failed}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request 'B7974D4D-C5DA-413E-AE3B-072C88D38D47' was aborted because the mirroring delegate never successfully initialized due to error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134421 "Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Import failed because applying the accumulated changes hit an unhandled exception., NSUnderlyingException=*** NSAllocateMemoryPages(103626821) failed}}
```

[Apple Developer Forums Link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688792#688792021)

Comment: Could you please share your NSPCKC setup? I'm facing a similar issue.. also, there seem to be some CloudKit bugs in iOS 15 b4, please check if the issue persists in b5 or let us know what version you are using.

Comment: @thisIsTheFoxe Both b4 and b5. NSPCKC setup is not changed since iOS 14.

Comment: There is definitely something broken with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer (and specifically NSCoudKitMirroringDelegate) since iOS 15 (beta 4, 5, 6 & 7). Prior to this it was working just fine. Since then, changes made on the device do not upload to iCloud. Changes made on iOS 14 devices continue to sync bidirectionally as expected. Hopefully it will be fixed in beta 8!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory issue fixed in iOS 15.5.